# How do I get pyspark on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I can get Spark on it through the Software Center, but how do I get pyspark?

Comment: I found these instructions make it much easier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhVYTNEe_-A https://github.com/mGalarnyk/Installations_Mac_Ubuntu_Windows/blob/master/Spark/Install_Apache_Spark_PySpark_Linux.ipynb

Answer (score 6):

`pyspark` is available via `pypi`.

So all you need to install `pyspark` is `pip` and execute the following command.

`pip install pyspark` or `sudo pip install pyspark`

Comment: Awsome Works Like A Charm

Answer (score 5):

`pyspark` is a python binding to the spark program written in Scala.

As long as you have Java 6+ and Python 2.6+ you can download pre-built binaries for spark from the [download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) page. Make sure that the `java` and `python` programs are on your `PATH` or that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set. Follow these steps to get started;

1. Unzip and move the unzipped directory to a working directory:

   > `tar -xzf spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`
   >
   > `mv spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6 /srv/spark-1.4.8`
2. Symlink the version of Spark to a `spark` directory:

   > `ln -s /srv/spark-1.4.8 /srv/spark`
3. Edit `~/.bash_profile` using your favorite text editor and add `Spark` to your `PATH` and set the `SPARK_HOME` environment variable:

   > `export SPARK_HOME=/srv/spark`
   >
   > `export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Now you should be able to execute pyspark by running the command `pyspark` in the terminal.

Some references:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html

https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/getting-started-with-spark-in-python

Comment: You also need git installed. Found out the hard way when installing on a clean virtual image...